# How to get the median price for the previous year?

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by

Given the below data how can I get the median squaremeterPrice for the previous year?

```
  city_code createdYear squaremeterPrice squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_the_current_year
0   26      2014            33273        39632.0
1   26      2014            37500        39632.0
2   26      2014            47428        39632.0
3   26      2014            39554        39632.0
4   26      2014            38893        39632.0
5   26      2013            34231        28841.0
6   26      2014            34344        39632.0
7   26      2014            44574        39632.0
8   26      2014            25202        39632.0
9   26      2014            39632        39632.0
10  26      2014            44504        39632.0
11  26      2013            23451        28841.0
...
```

In order to the get the squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_the_current_year I used below code:

```py
# adding the yearly average sqm price
median_squaremeterPrice_per_city = df.groupby(["city_code"])["squaremeterPrice"].median().to_frame("squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_the_current_year").reset_index()
df = df.merge(median_squaremeterPrice_per_city, left_on=["city_code"], right_on=["city_code"])
df
```

The expected output we look like:

```
  city_code createdYear squaremeterPrice squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_the_current_year   squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_1_year_prior
0   26      2014            33273        39632.0      28841.0
1   26      2014            37500        39632.0      28841.0
2   26      2014            47428        39632.0      28841.0
3   26      2014            39554        39632.0      28841.0
4   26      2014            38893        39632.0      28841.0
5   26      2013            34231        28841.0      whatever was the 2012 price
6   26      2014            34344        39632.0      28841.0
7   26      2014            44574        39632.0      28841.0
8   26      2014            25202        39632.0      28841.0
9   26      2014            39632        39632.0      28841.0
10  26      2014            44504        39632.0      28841.0
11  26      2013            23451        28841.0      whatever was the 2012 price
...
```

Comment: Can you add expected output for previous year from sample data?

Comment: Done. I hope it makes sense. It should also be grouped by city_code as the code refers to

Comment: do you want the median or average? In your code your calculating the median but your writing about average.

Comment: sorry, let me correct that, it should be median. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I do not understand why `squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_the_current_year` of 2013 and `squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_1_year_prior`of 2014 differ

Comment: Sure. Changed if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead your solution grouping by both columns `city_code` and `createdYear` with `median` and for previous year add `1` to years in `MultiIndex`, last use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for new columns:

```
median_squaremeterPrice_per_city_and_year = (df.groupby(["city_code", "createdYear"])["squaremeterPrice"]
                                               .median()
                                               .rename('squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_the_current_year'))
median_squaremeterPrice_per_city_and__prev_year =( median_squaremeterPrice_per_city_and_year
                                                   .rename(lambda x: x+1, level=1)
                                                   .rename('squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_the_prev_year'))

print (median_squaremeterPrice_per_city_and__prev_year)

df1 = (df.join(median_squaremeterPrice_per_city_and_year, on=['city_code','createdYear'])
         .join(median_squaremeterPrice_per_city_and__prev_year, on=['city_code','createdYear']))
```

---

```
print (df1)
    city_code  createdYear  squaremeterPrice  \
0          26         2014             33273   
1          26         2014             37500   
2          26         2014             47428   
3          26         2014             39554   
4          26         2014             38893   
5          26         2013             34231   
6          26         2014             34344   
7          26         2014             44574   
8          26         2014             25202   
9          26         2014             39632   
10         26         2014             44504   
11         26         2013             23451   

    squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_the_current_year  \
0                                             39223.5    
1                                             39223.5    
2                                             39223.5    
3                                             39223.5    
4                                             39223.5    
5                                             28841.0    
6                                             39223.5    
7                                             39223.5    
8                                             39223.5    
9                                             39223.5    
10                                            39223.5    
11                                            28841.0    

    squaremeterPrice_grouped_city_for_the_prev_year  
0                                           28841.0  
1                                           28841.0  
2                                           28841.0  
3                                           28841.0  
4                                           28841.0  
5                                               NaN  
6                                           28841.0  
7                                           28841.0  
8                                           28841.0  
9                                           28841.0  
10                                          28841.0  
11                                              NaN
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, if I was to go back two years instead of only the previous year, would I just change this line: .rename(lambda x: x+1, level=1) to  .rename(lambda x: x+2, level=1)?

Comment: @doomdaam - Not tested, but I think for 99% yes, because then join by 2 years ago.